# Jquery hide <tr> won't hide

Tags: jquery, row, hide, tr

I do not understand anymore. I search around and foud some solutions for what I like to have, But it is not working.
I have two options, I can change the line in a other color, or I can hide it.
I prefer the last option.

I want hide the row I click on. When this will work, I like to click on a other line and then I the hided line back in the table. So only the line what's click on has to be hide.

This is my code (Sorry forthe dutch comments in it):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'stdout');
    include("init.php");
    include("databaseopenen.php"); // openen van de database
    $Huidige_bestandsnaam = "beheer_menu.php";
    include("menuchecker.php"); // Check de filenaam in de tabel van het menu
    $query_menu_beheer = "SELECT * FROM tabel_menu ORDER BY menu_sub_van, menu_waarde";  
    $result_menu_beheer = mysqli_query($connect, $query_menu_beheer);
    $regel_menu_beheer = array();
    $verbergregel_toevoegen_muteren = "";
    $verbergregel_verwijderen = "";
    $verbergregel_presenteren = "";
    $link_menu_beheer = "";
    /* Het kan niet zijn dat er geen menu is. Want dan kan deze keuze niet gemaakt worden. */
    $verbergregel_presenteren = "";
    // *** regels vullen ***
    $i = 0;
    $regel = array();
    foreach($result_menu_beheer as $record_menu_beheer)
    { 
        $i = $i + 1;
        // *** regel maken ***
        $regel_menu_beheer[$i] = 
            "<tr id='regel[$i]' onclick='SelecteerRegel( this )' class='clickregel'>
            <td align = right>" . $record_menu_beheer['menu_waarde'] . "</td>
            <td align = right>" . $record_menu_beheer['menu_sub_van'] . "</td>
            <td align = left>" . $record_menu_beheer['menu_tekst'] . "</td>
            <td align = left>" . $record_menu_beheer['menu_link'] . "</td></tr>";
        // *** einde regel maken ***

    }
    // *** einde regels vullen ***
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
        <head>
            <!-- Created by Artisteer v4.3.0.60745 -->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Geldboom: Menu beheer</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0, maximum-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = device-width">    
            <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen">
            <!--[if lte IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.ie7.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.responsive.css" media="all">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script|Josefin+Sans&amp;subset=latin">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="extra.css" media="all">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lijsten.css"> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <script src="script.responsive.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function SelecteerRegel(x)
                { 
                    $('regel[x]').parents('tr').hide();
                } 
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="art-main">
                <?php
                    if (file_exists($filename)) {
                        include ("menu.php"); 
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="art-sheet clearfix">
                    <div class="art-layout-wrapper">
                        <div class="art-content-layout">
                            <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                            <?php include ("blok_links.php"); ?>
                            <!-- Content blok -->
                            <Table> 
                            <tr><td>
                            <div class="art-layout-cell art-content">
                            <article class="art-post art-article">
                            <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix">
                            <H1 align="center">Menu beheer</H1> 
                            <table>
                            <tr <?php echo $verbergregel_toevoegen_muteren; ?>><td>                         <p>Toevoegen en muteren kan in dit gebied plaatsvinden.</p></td></tr>
                            <tr <?php echo $verbergregel_verwijderen; ?>><td>
                            <p>Verwijderen ja/nee?</p></td></tr>
                        <tr <?php echo $verbergregel_presenteren; ?>><td>   <table id="Tabel" class="hovertabel">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Waarde</th><th>Sub van</th><th>Tekst</th><th>Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="datalijst"> <!-- Hier volgt de lijst -->
<?php
if (count($regel_menu_beheer)>>0)
{
for ($i = 1 ; $i <= count($regel_menu_beheer); $i++) { echo $regel_menu_beheer[$i]; }
}
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
</tfoot>
</table>
</td></tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </article>
                                    </div>
                                </td></tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- einde Content blok -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please, provide a minimal, reproducible example for more help. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: freedomn-m, you mean I need this?
$('#regel['+x+']').parents('tr').hide();

It still does not work

I see the rows. But when I click on it. nothing happen.

Comment: I think I need .rowIndex. So I get: 

$('#regel['+x.rowIndex+']').parents('tr').hide(); 

But still no hided row.

Comment: I didn't look closely enough (a *minimal* code would have helped here) - the `x` in `SelecteerRegel(x)` is "this" from onclick, so will be the element you're already clicking - so you just need `$(x).hide()`

Comment: When you use `[]` in a selector, it's not an array, but attributes, eg `$("[onclick]")` will give you everything that has an onclick attribute.  So would not be `.rowIndex` as in `#regel[3]` as that's not a *selector*.  You could use `$("[id=regel").eq(x.rowIndex)` - but not needed `x` is the row being clicked, so just `$(x).hide()`

Comment: Awsome!!! It works.
Thanks for the support and the explonation..
This and the opposite was wat I needed:
    $(x).siblings().show();
    $(x).hide();